# Tag Merge Request - Mac related tags

Tags: support, retag-request

macosxserver -> mac-osx-server
osx-server -> mac-osx-server

osx -> mac-osx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also consider addressing:

- leopardserver -> leopard-server
- osx-10.6 -> snow-leopard
- osx -> mac-osx
- macosx  -> mac-osx

The most difficult to clean up will be **mac**.  Work should be done to separate the use of **mac** as a description of the physical address from its usage to identify Apple computers.

```
leopard - 39
leopardserver - 2
snow-leopard - 81
snow-leopard-server - 40
tiger
osx - 248
macosx - 635
macosxserver - 158
mac-osx-server - 9
osx-10.6 - 10
osx - 248
macosx - 635
mac - 265
```

Comment: After separation perhaps mac should become mac-address to eliminate confusion.

Comment: Now we just need a feature to black-hole a tag (the way [subjective] was perma-killed) so people are forced to use, say, mac-address or mac-os... Or did that go in and I was snoozing that day?